# Multiple Y Axis - Graphic Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I have this code which generates a graph with two Y-axes, using the Plotly library in javascript.

The chart is generated correctly, but I can't change colors to my data. I'd like to turn the bar chart data black and the line chart data red. Any help to be able to change the color of my chart data?

```
           TESTERL = document.getElementById('freq_cZero_ppv_v')

            var trace1 = {
                x: data.Delay,
                y: data.Amp_X_V,
                type: 'scatter',
                name: 'Vertical',
                hovertemplate: '<b>Tran:</b> %{y}<br><b>Retardo:</b> %{x}<br><extra></extra>',
                yaxis: 'y2',
            }

            var trace2 = {
                x: data.Delay,
                y: data.ZCFreq_X_V,
                type: 'bar',
                name: 'Frecuencia',
                hovertemplate: '<b>Freq:</b> %{y}<br><b>Retardo:</b> %{x}<br><extra></extra>'
            }

            var data = [trace1, trace2];
            var layout = {
                xaxis: { title: 'Retardo entre pozos en la fila (ms)', showspikes: true, spikemode: 'toaxis' },
                yaxis: { title: 'Frecuencia cruce x ZERO (Hz)', side: 'left',showspikes: true, spikemode: 'toaxis', showgrid: false, line: { color: '#252525' } },
                yaxis2: {
                    title: 'Amplificación PPV (%)',
                    overlaying: 'y',
                    side: 'right',
                    showspikes: true,
                    spikemode: 'toaxis',
                    showgrid: false
                },
                title: 'Amplificación de Vibraciones Onda Elemental (PPV) & Frecuencias c/Zero',
                showlegend: true,
                legend: {
                    "orientation": "h"
                },
                images: [{
                    'source': './../img/GBLogo.jpg',
                    'xref': 'paper',
                    'yref': 'paper',
                    'x': 0.9,
                    'y': 0.8,
                    'sizex': 0.1,
                    'sizey': 0.1,
                    'opacity': 0.8,
                    'xanchor': 'right',
                    'yanchor': 'bottom'
                }]
            }

            Plotly.newPlot(TESTERL, data, layout, { scrollZoom: true, editable: true, responsive: true, displaylogo: false })
```